# What is the dll file name of the standard c library on windows?

Tags: c, windows, dll

I'm using libffi to load dlls at runtime on multiple platforms. The correct system paths are automatically searched, I just need to know what the name of the system dll is on the Microsoft platform housing the standard c library functions.

Comment: That's like asking which DTD the Netscape browser uses to parse websites :-)

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What's driving the question? Why do you need to know about a C runtime to load a DLL? Many many DLLs don't even depend on a C runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows ships with a C runtime in  msvcrt.dll. If you are writing a self-contained program and want to call functions from the C standard library, then perhaps this is what you need.

If your program uses libraries that are linked against other C runtimes, this will be no good to you. But in that case, you don't need to do anything special since your compiler/linker will make the C standard library available.

If you want to call functions in a C runtime used by one of the DLLs you load, that's a problem. The runtime could be linked statically, or it could be one of many different dynamic runtimes.

Comment: I can specify the call abi at runtime so what abi does the msvcrt use since it does have signature matching functions of the stdc library?

I have options: 

CDECL - mac os unix
STDCALL - Used for calling functions declared with stdcall on Windows.

WINAPI - used for calling windows system functions.

Comment: All C runtimes I've ever seen on Windows use cdecl.

Comment: Although it sounds conflicting, I'm assuming that it would be STDCALL. Cuz I don't think its a windows api (msvcrt) and the macs and unices are using what my system calls cdecl. The standard c libary calling convention, which windows is accused of not using.

Comment: C runtimes on Windows use cdecl. Windows API functions use stdcall. One reason for cdecl for C runtimes are functions like printf that cannot be implemented with stdcall.

Comment: Wait a sec, actually I read you wrong you said C runtimes, not c libraries! Must be cdecl.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Linux and Unix-like systems, Windows does not have a "natural" compiler tool chain built in, and thus no C library. Each compiler has to ship its own. Microsoft's own MSVC links against a dynamic library like `msvcrtxxx.dll` (with some sort of versioning; newer versions of Windows ship with some version of this); if you compile with GCC, you have a C runtime for that compiler somewhere that you need to ship (or link statically with `-static-libgcc`).

Similarly, there isn't a central library repository akin to `/usr/lib` or a strong versioning scheme, and so typical Windows applications often end up shipping set up dynamic libraries each for their own.

(The core platform components of Windows are the Windows API libraries like `Kernel32.exe`, `GDI.exe` and `User.exe`, which any C compiler that has the Windows API headers can link against.)

Comment: using libffi there is no linking to the library itself. It will be loaded from disk and the symbols will be declared locally at runtime so, linking to the target library or including its header is actually not a problem unless the libary does not expose access to a required symbol that cannot be statically defined.

Comment: @TristonJ.Taylor: Well, you can't really link meaningfully at runtime if you don't know the target signature of the function you're looking for. The signature is not stored in the binary object (nor is any *type* information, for that matter). But this isn't really about the C library, is it? Because your C program wouldn't even *run* without some type of C library.

Comment: but I do see your point that when I cross compile my core application, it will have to link to a runtime somewhere!

Comment: That's why my question is about the c libary. I'm translating the headers to software prototyping engine. The function sigs, types, enums and constants are already defined. It is the implementation specific constants that will create the most 'bugs' in need of resolution.

Comment: So in a sense, all that I need is the libary path with matching signatures.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do or what you're asking. Just to build a self-contained executable, you *must* have a C library around at compile time for static or load-time linking, *and* that C library must have been built itself with the same headers that you're using in your application. If the C library is only linked for load-time (shared objects in Linux, DLLs in Windows), then you need to ship the library along with your program (or rely on your OS to have a copy). *All other* libraries can be loaded at runtime later on, but that's a separate topic.